# Enable Gutenberg on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, editor, block-editor

I have this custom post type:

```
function create_posttype() {
  register_post_type( 'companies',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'شرکتهای عضو' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'شرکت' )
      ),
      'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'custom-fields', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'companies'),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

Which shows classic editor in WordPress admin area. I tried to replace 'editor' with 'gutenberg' in the supports array which doesn't work.
I also added this code to my function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199629/how-to-disable-gutenberg-editor-for-certain-post-types/52199630):

```
add_filter('gutenberg_can_edit_post_type', 'prefix_disable_gutenberg');
function prefix_disable_gutenberg($current_status, $post_type)
{
    if ($post_type === 'companies') return true;
    return $current_status;
}
```

How can I have a Gutenberg editor on my custom post type?

Comment: this article may help you - https://webomnizz.com/how-to-enable-gutenberg-editor-with-custom-post-type/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

For Gutenberg to work in a Custom Post Type you need to enable both the `editor` in `supports` (which you already have) and `show_in_rest`. So add `'show_in_rest' => true,` to your post registration arguments array.

Comment: Glad it works, you are welcome.

Comment: Works fine, Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Start by registering a Gutenberg WordPress custom type. The process is fairly easy and involves adding the following the code snippet.

```
/*Register WordPress  Gutenberg CPT */
function cw_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        // WordPress CPT Options Start
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Portfolio' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Portfolio' )
            ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'public' => true,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
            'show_in_rest' => true,
            'supports' => array('editor')
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cw_post_type' );
```

add the show_in_rest key and set it to true via your custom post type.

```
'show_in_rest' => true,
   'supports' => array('editor')
```

As you can see, the above code snippet just set the ‘show_in_rest’ parameter to ‘TRUE’. After this step, when you create or edit a custom post type, you will see the Gutenberg editor visible and enabled.

All the steps and query discuss in detailed at 
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/gutenberg-wordpress-custom-post-type/